# Left outer join returning more rows than no join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am perplexed by the following issue. I am doing a left outer join and it's returning MORE rows than no join at all.

```
select COUNT(*) specimen_id from QuickLabDump a
left outer join PracticeandPhysician c
on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
 where 
DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) =12
and
DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered])=2011
```

yields `108387`

whereas

```
select COUNT(*) specimen_id from QuickLabDump a
 where 
DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) =12
and
DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered])=2011
```

yields `108357`

Shouldn't they be returning the same exact amount of rows?

Comment: If you wanna eliminate duplicates you can use COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second table may have more rows per 1 row in main table, thats the point

Comment: how do i not return duplicates?

Comment: Use count(distinct specimen_id) instead of count(*)

Comment: I've hit the reputation cap for today, can you all revote me tomorrow? 8-D

Answer (score 5):

This happens when the joined `PracticeandPhysician` table contains multiple rows for a key in the `QuickLabDump` table.

This query

```
select COUNT(*), c.practicecode, a.[Requesting Physician],speciment_id
from QuickLabDump a
left outer join PracticeandPhysician c
on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
    and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where 
DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) =12
and
DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered])=2011
GROUP BY c.practicecode, a.[Requesting Physician], speciment_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Should tell you which rows have duplicates.

Comment: how do i not return duplicates?

Comment: @I__ Which data *should* be returned in that case, and how? You have to squish it or discard it.

Comment: @I__ First, figure out which rows cause duplicates. Is this because multiple physicians requested the same specimen, or is this because your data contains unintended duplicates? The way to fix the problem would depend on your answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Perplexing, yes, but understandable.

If you want to see what you're getting from the first query that is not in the second query, SELECT the records in the first resultset that are not in the second resultset.

You might also try adding DISTINCT to your queries.

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates in the `PractiveandPhysician` table.

It's only if you join on a unique value that you never get more records.

Comment: how do i not return duplicates?

Comment: @I__ - What makes you think that you are not returning duplicates?